# Simple if/elif statement + raw_input why dosen't work

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a problem with simple if statement. I want user to press a key '1','2' or '3' to choose any option then program will do something. For a test it just prints  text for example "Wybrano 2" after pressing '2'.

Here is my code:

```
if raw_input() == '1':
        print "Wybrano 1"

elif raw_input() == '2':
        print "Wybrano 2"

elif raw_input() == '3':
        print "Wybrano 3"
```

So if I press 1 it correctly prints "Wybrano 1" but when I press 2 or 3 the program does  nothing.

Comment: You want to store the `raw_input()` to a variable before you compare them.... if you are using the default `raw_input()`

Comment: please post the code of `raw_input()`

Comment: Because it compares first `if` and test fails for 2 and 3 , goes to `elif` and waits for you to enter the input.. so put `raw_input()` outside of `if..elif` and  save to in any variable

Comment: @KalpeshDusane that is only if hes using default `raw_input()` like daniel pointed out, he could have override it..... we don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**When i press 2 or 3 program does not nothing** is wrong. It is waiting for you for next input.

Let me tell you how this is working.

- `raw_input` is python function for accepting user input.(I know you are aware of this :) )
- When you execute code, first it will go to "`if`" statement. `'if'` statement has `'raw_input'` function after it. So, it waits for your input.
- When you enter '1', `"1" = "1"`, it gives you expected output and come out of code.
- However, next time when you again execute code, again `'raw_input'` after `'if'` is executed waiting for your input. When you input '2' and since `'1' == '2'` is false, code goes to next `'elif'` statement. After `'elif'` there is `'raw_input'` function which is waiting for input again.
- **Therefore, you got feel, program does nothing.**
- Same happens when you enter '3'.

**Example of above explained behavior**

```
if raw_input("Enter number : ") == '1':

    print "Wybrano 1"
elif raw_input("Enter number : ") == '2':

    print "Wybrano 2"
elif raw_input("Enter number : ") == '3':

    print "Wybrano 3"
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python c.py
Enter number : 1
Wybrano 1

C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python c.py
Enter number : 2
Enter number : 2
Wybrano 2

C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python c.py
Enter number : 3
Enter number : 3
Enter number : 3
Wybrano 3
```

**How to make your code working ?**

Answer is simple. As explained by **@MooingRawr** in first comment, just save user input in some variable and then check.

```
x = raw_input("Enter number : ")
if  x == '1':
    print "Wybrano 1"
elif x == '2':
    print "Wybrano 2"
elif x == '3':
    print "Wybrano 3"
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python c.py
Enter number : 1
Wybrano 1

C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python c.py
Enter number : 2
Wybrano 2

C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python c.py
Enter number : 3
Wybrano 3

C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>
```

Comment: Now it is so obvious ;) Thanks you all